# Perfect-Notifications: Unable to write frame

Tags: swift, linux, apple-push-notifications, perfect, perfect-notifications

I'm sending push notifications like so:

```
    var items:[APNSNotificationItem] = [.customPayload("body",body),.contentAvailable]
    if alert
    {
        items.append(.badge(badge))
        items.append(.alertBody(message))
        items.append(.alertTitle(title))
        items.append(.sound("default"))
    }
    let n = NotificationPusher(apnsTopic: Constants.notificationsAppId)
    n.pushAPNS(
        configurationName: notificationsAppId,
        deviceTokens: deviceIDs,
        notificationItems: items) {
            responses in
            LogFile.debug("Notification Result:"+String(describing:responses))
    }
```

It works fine initially, and responses look like this:

```
Notification Result:[200 OK: ]
```

but after the service runs for a while, it ends up looking like this

```
Notification Result:[500 Internal Server Error: Unable to write frame]
```

And the notification is not sent. Restarting the service makes it okay, again.

What might be causing this issue?

Edit: This also happens on Mac OS X when a local instance has been running without activity for a couple of hours

Comment: error in certificates when you try to send push it not send and server is crashed, (check certificates, device token)

Comment: @Tyress, we you able to work around this issue? This appears to still be a problem in the latest version of Perfect-Notifications.

Comment: @Arnold we stopped relying on notifications. Would be great to see some progress on this though